# For $f(x)=x_1 x_2$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, calculate $\| f'(x) \|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

$$f'(x)=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \qquad x_1  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\| f'(x) \|=\| f'(x) \|_\infty=\max \{ \lvert x_2 \lvert, \lvert x_1 \lvert \}$$

I have a doubt, because there is this result on my book :

$$\| f'(x) \|=\| f'(x) \|_\infty=\lvert x_2 \lvert+ \lvert x_1 \lvert $$

But $$x \in \mathbb{R}^n :  \| x \|_\infty=\max_{i \in \{ 1,...,n \} } \lvert x_i \lvert $$

Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: I agree, the sum is for this $\| f'(x) \|_1=\lvert x_2 \lvert+ \lvert x_1 \lvert$ By the other side, why this idetification of norms $\| f'(x) \|=\| f'(x) \|_\infty$? Without subindex, it's intended to be the pythagorean one, $\| f'(x) \|_2$, Isn't it?

Comment: If $f$ is a function of two independent variables, $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1 x_2$, then it is a mistake to write it as a function of one variable, $f(x)$.  The notation $f'(x)$ expressly applies only when we have a function of one variable.  If you wish to express the pair of partial derivatives, $(\partial f/\partial x_1,\partial f/\partial x_2)$, this vector is the *gradient* of $f$, and the proper notation is $\nabla f$ or $\operatorname{grad} f$.

Comment: @hardmath, I think it's clear enough that $x=(x_1,x_2)$. And many people would write $f'$ for the derivative, your assertion that this is only a 1-variable notation is not accepted by many.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion probably arises from the difference between a vector and it's induced matrix norm:

> For any vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have
>   $$
> \| x \|_{\infty}
> = \max_{i = 1}^{n} | x_i|,
> $$
>   whereas for a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, the *induced* matrix norm is
>   $$
> \| A \|_{\infty}
> := \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \\ \| x \|_{\infty} = 1}} \| Ax \|_{\infty}
> = \max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}} \sum_{j = 1}^{n} | a_{ij} |,
> $$
>   which is therefore called the "row-sum-norm".

---

Now, your matrix, the gradient, is
$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
x_2 \\ x_1
\end{bmatrix}
$
and therefore, $\| A \|_{\infty} = | x_2 | + | x_1 |$.